# TypeError on ionic build

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

when executing command "ionic build" shows this message:

> Error parsing /home/saxa/myApp/config.xml: TypeError: Cannot read property 'widget' of null (CLI v1.4.0-alpha.6)

Comment: Include content of config.xml in your question please.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show us your config.xml? There might be an issue with the  tag at the beginning of it and this can cause build issues since the config.xml defines properties of the app such as the name, package name and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys the best solution i found for my problem was to re-install everything from scratch .There was also a problem with the server connection and the version of node in my computer.For similar problems i found that the issue origin was the permission of the user.My opinion is to stick at ionic's documentation.